# Entity framework audit

Tags: entity-framework, auditing

I'm trying to add auditing to my application. The problem that I encountered is that I can not get some old and new values from non primitive types. For example, if I have an entity Person, I can easily get name, age, but  I can not get any property of the Country:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Country { get;set;}
}
```

and country might look like:

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get;set;}
    public string Name { get;set;}
}
```

Currently the code that returns new/old value looks like (dbEntry is DbEntityEntry):

```
foreach (var prop in dbEntry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
{
    string oldValue = dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(prop) == null ? null : dbEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<object>(prop).ToString();
    string newValue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(prop) == null ? null : dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(prop).ToString();
}
```

How can I get information related to the country (I want to have country name in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried existing solutions ?

https://www.nuget.org/packages/TrackerEnabledDbContext

Comment: Nope, I implemented my own solution. Does your suggested library track any changes in collections?

Comment: If you mean does it track entities that are in collections, then yes. I wrote it my self btw. Although i am not sure if i understand your question correctly..

Comment: Here is another one: [Audit.EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Audit.entityframework/)